# ASP.NET Core API authenticate using JWT bearer tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, bearer-token

I have a new API I would like to authenticate using an external security provider (auth server). I have the following code, however I get an error when call my authenticated action with everything set up.

Startup.cs:

```
public async void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddScoped<ITemperatureLoggerRepository<ConsolidatedTables>, TemperatureLoggerRepository>();

            services.AddDbContext<TemperatureLoggerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString:TemperatureLoggerDB"]));

            services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
            {
                swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Temperature Logger API", Version = "Version 1" });
                swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                });
                swagger.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id = "Bearer"
                                }
                            },
                            new string[] {}
                    }
                });
            });

            Response<List<Client>> response = await services.AddAuthServer(Configuration);

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var signingKeys = new List<SymmetricSecurityKey>();
                foreach (var client in response.Data)
                {
                    signingKeys.Add(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(client.Base64Secret)));
                }

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKeys = signingKeys
                };
            }).AddOAuthValidation();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();
            
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Temperature Logger API");
            });
        }
```

AuthServer.cs that calls a list of clients that will be allowed to access API:

```
public static async Task<Response<List<Client>>> AddAuthServer(this IServiceCollection collection, IConfiguration config)
        {
            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                UseCookies = true
            };

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
            {
                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", config["Jwt:ClientId"]),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", config["Jwt:ClientSecret"])
                });
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(config["Jwt:Issuer"]);
                var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(config["Jwt:Issuer"] + "oauth2/token", content);
                var result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(result);
            }

            var clientHandler2 = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                UseCookies = true
            };
            using (var httpClient2 = new HttpClient(clientHandler2))
            {
                httpClient2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _tokenResponse.access_token);
                using (var response = await httpClient2.GetAsync(config["Jwt:Issuer"] + "api/Client/GetIdKeys"))
                {
                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                    //string clientsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response<List<Client>>>();
                }
            }
        }
```

HomeController.cs (Authenticated Action):

```
[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/home")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Ok("Welcome to our Protected World!");
        }
    }
```

RESULT:
[image]

Please asssist how I can get this working. The API also has its on ClientId and ClientSecret assigned to it.

Comment: Can you try moving `app.UseAuthentication();` to before `app.UseAuthorization();`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I do that, now I get the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint HomeController.Index '' contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization.

Comment: I'm not sure but think you need to call `services.AddAuthorization();`

Comment: Still no luck, I tried the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem and it was pretty straight forward and I missed it. It really had nothing to do with getting a list of my audience or any extra configuration. I needed to decode the keys I got from my store:

```
var signingKeys = new List<SymmetricSecurityKey>();
foreach (var client in response.Data)
{
   signingKeys.Add(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(/***base64Secret***/)));
}
```